# Dynamic WHERE clause in setDataSource in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, data-source, qgsvectorlayer, where-clause

In PyQGIS, I want to create a layer according to the value of two variables (not hardcode values). This is a piece of my code, but the layer is not valid.

```
var_a = "Miami" #hardcode

var_b = "US"    #hardcode

uri.setDataSource("RRR", "My_table", "geom", "city = var_a AND country = var_b","field_id")

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), 'LayerIni','postgres')
```

Any ideas how use variables in a WHERE clause in setDataSource?